# AWS: How do I get the size of Multipart Uploads in the AWS S3 SDK v3?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using the AWS S3 v3 SDK and want to find out the size(in bytes or MB or GB ) of all the multipart uploads.

I tried using ListMultipartUploadsCommand but this does not give the size.

Below is the documentation I was referring to
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/index.html

Which API do I have to use to get the relevant data?

Comment: check ListObjectsV2: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html

Comment: You need to call ListMultipartUploads, then for each multipart upload, call [ListParts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/listpartscommand.html) to get the list of parts for the upload and add up the sizes of all of the parts.  That will just tell you what the size currently is, not the final size.

Comment: @AnonCoward which property tells you the size? I can't see one unless I'm missing something?

Comment: The `Size` of each `Part` element in the `Parts` array of `ListPartsCommandOutput`